# Why can't this higher kinded lifetime associated type trait bound be satisfied?

Tags: rust

```rust
trait A<'self_>: 'self_ {
    type I;
}
trait AMut
where
    Self: for<'self_> A<'self_>,
    for<'self_> <Self as A<'self_>>::I: 'static,
{
    fn mutate_self(&mut self);
}

fn foo<X>(x: &mut X)
where
    X: 'static + for<'a> A<'a> + AMut,
    for<'a> <X as A<'a>>::I: 'static,
{
    x.mutate_self();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=6511c528a51b9ed965faaabfcfe0c84d)

This errors out with

```
error[E0280]: the requirement `for<'self_> <Self as A<'self_>>::I: 'static` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:4:1
   |
4  |   trait AMut
   |   ^     ---- required by a bound in this
   |  _|
   | |
5  | | where
6  | |     Self: for<'self_> A<'self_>,
7  | |     for<'self_> <Self as A<'self_>>::I: 'static,
   | |                                         ------- required by this bound in `AMut`
8  | | {
9  | |     fn mutate_self(&mut self);
10 | | }
   | |_^

error[E0280]: the requirement `for<'self_> <X as A<'self_>>::I: 'static` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:14:34
   |
4  | trait AMut
   |       ---- required by a bound in this
...
7  |     for<'self_> <Self as A<'self_>>::I: 'static,
   |                                         ------- required by this bound in `AMut`
...
14 |     X: 'static + for<'a> A<'a> + AMut,
   |                                  ^^^^
```

I would've thought that the bound on line 15 would satisfy the bound on line 7. What am I missing?

Comment: I think it is this issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27113. You can't have HKL on the lhs of a where clause

Comment: @ker I'm willing to believe that. I just found out now that replacing the rhs `'static` with a `Send` makes the bounds compile, though. Weird.

Comment: @ker Ah, it compiles, but then actually trying to [`impl` the trait for a type never works](http://is.gd/hRsrD3).

Comment: For this particular case, adding a generic lifetime `AMut` and `foo`, instead of HKL, [works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=c5fb5fd30be8b67d4c00aa27a7fc7a11).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this?

```
trait A<'self_>: 'self_ {
    type I;
}
trait AMut<'a>
where
    Self: A<'a>,
    <Self as A<'a>>::I: 'static,
{
    fn mutate_self(&mut self);
}

fn foo<X>(x: &mut X)
where
    X: 'static + for<'a> A<'a> + for<'a> AMut<'a>,
    for<'a> <X as A<'a>>::I: 'static,
{
    x.mutate_self();
}
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, the point of my question back then was to mitigate the 'contagiousness' of lifetimes, as well as to understand why something that should've worked by the rules instead failed to. Your solution sidesteps the issue by giving `rustc` leeway to descend into corresponding binders rather than solving the types at the top level. The original error demonstrates a fundamental weakness in `rustc`'s current implementation that `chalk` integration was/is supposed to fix IIUC (I've not kept up with the news).

Comment: Hello @user, yes this is an old question :-) I don't remember exactly my reasoning. I found strange the "where: for" usage, which is generally used with closure [HRTBs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html), [Rust RFC 0387](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0387-higher-ranked-trait-bounds.md) and I proposed an solution. I can remove this idea if you think is not relevant.

Comment: i dig the username, @user